# Error when refreshing the page with router vue.js

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, vue-router

when I press F5 the components disappear.only happens when I use **beforeEnter: auth**. if I navigate within the pages with router-link it works well

router/Auth.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default (to, from, next) => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/user/login');
    }
  });
};
```

router/index.js

```
{
  path: 'edit',
  name: 'edit_profile',
  component: edit,
  beforeEnter: auth,
}
```

this happens when I press F5: **Nothing is shown**

[image]

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @AlbertoRivera nothing is shown when I press F5 on that route

Comment: Have you tried to move tour firebase integration to the Auth Mounted() event?

Comment: @felipekm No, I'm new to vue.js, any reference I can read?

Comment: Yeah sure, here is: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted
I also created a gist that could help you: https://gist.github.com/felipekm/28a9a795c5c46e857c5f1410dec11682

Comment: @felipekm error :( https://gist.github.com/felipekm/28a9a795c5c46e857c5f1410dec11682

Comment: Yeah right, actually you must to create a component and set it on your route configuration, the component will have the mounted() event covered with your firebase logic. Check the gist.